# TFS 2015 Release Definition "TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator."

Tags: tfs, release-management, tfs-2015

I have installed TFS 2015 update 2.1 on server. I can create and execute build definitions. All project Collections upgraded from TFS 2013 and working. Team users can access Team projects and make check-in, get latest etc.. But i can't create Release Definition from TFS Web UI. Whenever i try create release definiton still have same error : "TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator."

I tried repair and reinstall TFS 2015 but didn't work.

Tfs_Configuration : TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 14.95.25229.0

Tfs_DefaultCollection : TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 14.92.25229.0

TFS 2015 Version : 14.95.25229.0

I also recovered sysadmin access as it says :

[TF30040: The database is not correctly configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852900/tf30040-the-database-is-not-correctly-configured)

And all Tfs Databases Online and MULTI_USER as it says :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248602%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

And finally installed new Windows 8.1 on another computer. Then installed SQL Server 2014 and TFS 2015 Update 2.1 from scratch. And still relase definition cant be created. 
Should i configure or install something else?

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP):*

In Tfs_DefaultCollection's stored procedures : [Release].[prc_ReleaseDefinition_Add] procedure takes parameter called `@id`. But our requests send parameter as @Id and therefor Sql returns exception. So I changed procedure parameter to @Id and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your database is configured with Turkish collation. We discovered this bug recently and it will be fixed with TFS update 3. 
Meanwhile, the fix that you have made to the stored procedure is correct. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Issue still there! TFS Update 3