# TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing step 'Ensure initial catalog data exists' for component InstallFrameworkApplication during Install

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to upgrade/install TFS 2017 over TFS 2015 update4. I've got SQL server 2016 installed.

TFS 2017 installed successfully and while trying to Create Team Project collection through TFS Administration console, i got the error as below

> TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing step 'Ensure
>   initial catalog data exists' for component InstallFrameworkApplication
>   during Install
>
> TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team
>   Foundation Server administrator.. For more information, see the
>   configuration log.

[image: Error Image]

Note: I've deleted the previous exiting TFS database and re-tried, still the error exits. Please suggest a solution

Comment: And what do the complete logs say? See the link at the bottom of the installer. I suspect your server collation may be unsupported or some other server level configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First, suggest you to check the **Event Eview** on TFS server, if there are some more error info for troubleshooting.

If your process of upgrading to Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2017 has been succeed( Double check this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/11/30/upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017/), if you have any thing missed). The error occurs during the usage of Team Project Collection Creation through Administration Console.

You could try to use below solution: add yourself as a sysadmin by starting SQL Server in single user mode follow below steps:

> **1.** Open the Configuration Manager tool from the "SQL Server 2016| Configuration" menu
>
> **2.** Stop the SQL Server Instance you need to recover
>
> **3.** Navigate to the “Advanced” tab, and in the Properties text box add “;–m” to the end of the list in the “Startup parameters” option
>
> **4.** Click the “OK” button and restart the SQL Server Instance
>   **NOTE:** make sure there is no space between “;” and “-m”, the registry parameter parser is sensitive to such typos. You should see
>   an entry in the SQL Server ERRORLOG file that says “SQL Server started
>   in single-user mode.”
>
> **5.** After the SQL Server Instance starts in single-user mode, the Windows Administrator account is able to connect to SQL Server using
>   the sqlcmd utility using Windows authentication. You can use
>   Transact-SQL commands such as "sp_addsrvrolemember" to add an existing
>   login (or a newly created one) to the sysadmin server role. The
>   following example adds the account "Buck" in the "CONTOSO" domain to
>   the SQL Server "sysadmin" role:
>
> EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'CONTOSO\Buck', 'sysadmin'; 
> GO
>
> **6.** Once the sysadmin access has been recovered, remove the “;-m” from the startup parameters using the Configuration Manager and
>   restart the SQL Server Instance

More details please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10853481/5391065) of a similar issue.