# TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator

Tags: tfs

Can someone help me with
how to connect new tfs 2017 update1 to the existing database (MSSQLserver2016) that is in other server. have tried setting this up, but while accessing the tfs application url, it shows as
TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator

Comment: Do you mean that you want to install a new TFS 2017 application-tier server using the existing datatbase? or just a reinstall on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

If just reinstall TFS on the same machine, then you can point it at the database during configuration. When you reinstall, you should be able to choose the "**Application Tier Only**" configuration option, which will ask you to point it to the correct databases.

If you want to install a new TFS server using the existing database, after the configuration you can try [RemapDBs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs) to redirect TFS to its databases.

I'd recommend backing up the DBs first as a precaution, then [Restore an application-tier server](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-application-tier-server) or [Restore data to a different server than the current one for TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance)

Back to the specific error: `TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server`, it may be caused by many reasons. Here is a similar thread for your reference: [TF30040: The database is not correctly configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852900/tf30040-the-database-is-not-correctly-configured)