# Restoring tfs from backup - problem with attaching collection

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I have backups of TFS created by TFS' 2015 scheluded backups and I'm trying to restore them on different server, but for some reason I cannot even attach collection (not even talking about `Tfs_Configuration` yet). I managed to restore backups via TFS Console -> Scheluded Backups -> Restore

but I cannot attach it

```
TfsConfig registerDB /sqlInstance:SQL\NEW_TFS /databaseName:Tfs_Collection1

The following exception was caught while trying to validate the database:
TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.
```

What's the reason behind this?

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10853481/10522960 to solve that, but it doesn't help at all

Also

> First, please make sure you are a member of the Team Foundation Administrators security group and a member of the sysadmin security group for any SQL Server databases that Team Foundation Server uses.

There's no such group (`Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups -> Groups`), shouldn't it be created by tfs?

```
TfsConfig offlineDetach /configurationDB:SQL\NEW_TFS;Tfs_Configuration /collectionDB:SQL\NEW_TFS;Tfs_Collection1

The database 'SQL\NEW_TFS;Tfs_Collection1' is hosting Team Project Collection with ID 'da9b771c-a149-62d1-a7b0-e
1ad79977102', however this collection is not registered in the specified configuration database.
```

I've been trying to change Application Id inside

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.CONFIG
```

to `da9b771c-a149-62d1-a7b0-e1ad79977102` but it doesn't help at all

Does anyone has an idea what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Did you detach the collection before the backup was taken?

Comment: @JamesReed Backups are automatic and I've seen somewhere that they're not detached, so no :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restore the standard backups without detaching a collection you need to restore the configuration database first. You will also need to [update the TFS GUID](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee349259(v=vs.60)) otherwise it will identify as the same TFS server as the original and weird stuff will happen in visual studio.

When you detach a collection all of the collection specific configuration is copied from the configuration database in to the collection database. This process makes the collection portable, note that this will also take the collection offline. You can then back up the collection database and restore it to a new TFS server with a "clean" configuration database. Once the backup is restored you will be able to attach the collection.

Attaching the collection will then copy all of the collection specific configuration in to the new configuration database

Comment: I used `changeServerId` and it told me that `[Error] [Database Verifications] TF400311: The database connection strings are n
ot valid and cannot be automatically corrected. To fix this problem, use the TFS
Config RemapDBs command-line tool to correct the database connection strings.`. So I used `RemapDbs` and it worked - the collections are attachable, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to use `TfsConfig registerDB` for collections? According to the manual, [RegisterDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2019#registerdb) moves configuration database only:

> Use registerDB to update name of the server that hosts the
>   configuration database in Azure DevOps Server. You might use this
>   command when restoring the configuration database to new hardware or
>   when changing the domain of a deployment.

To attach your restored collection, you can use Team Foundation Server Administration console: [Attach the collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=azure-devops#4-attach-the-collection)

Comment: The thing is that `attach the collection` from TFS Console doesn't see any collection on this SQL instance meanwhile it's straight restored from backup via `Restore` option

Comment: @Joelty It seems like current user does not have permissions to the restored collection database. `Before you start your move, make sure that you're an administrator on the servers and in the software used by both the deployment you're moving from, and the one you're moving to.` Check permission by this manual: [Add server-level administrators to Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/add-administrator?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

1. Detach collection using "Team Foundation Server Administration console".
2. Create backup for detached collection.
3. Restore backup on destination sql server.
4. Attache again collection to destination server using "Team Foundation Server Administration console".